# Initializing a list of integers in c++

Tags: c++

I need to put 32 bits of integers into a list. Problem is, I can't seem to fill that list up properly.

Ex. I need to get from this: `01000100011100111111000000000000`

to this: `list[0]=0`, `list[1]=1`, `list[2]=0`, `list[3]=0`, and so on.

The number is being given to me as an integer through standard output.

Here is my go at it:

```
int binary;
cin << binary;
int *list = new int [32];
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    list[i] = binary % 10;
    binary /= 10;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    cout << list[i];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You start out by indexing out of bounds, accessing `list[4]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `new` here.

Comment: Also, dividing a variable named `binary` with the decimal value `10` doesn't seem very binary to me. You might want to think through you variable naming, or your algorithm.

Comment: And how can a number be given through standard out?

Comment: And of course, use `std::vector`.  (The simplest solution is probably to use `push_back` for each binary digit, then `std::reverse`.)

Comment: I edited my trivial errors, like accessing out of bounds. Also, I'm sorry, I am not familiar with std::vector, push_back or std::revers and their purpose. Would you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

The following loop results in out-of-bounds array access:

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    list[i] = ...
```

`list`'s elements are numbered from zero to three.

Also, the following looks iffy:

```
list[i] = binary % 2;
binary /= 10;
```

The two numbers should either both be `2` or both be `10`.

Answer (score 2):

This part:
`int *list = new int [4];` creates an array that is indexed from 0 to 3 and You're trying to access list[4] later.

Answer (score 1):

you should divide by 2 and start with index as 3

```
for(i=3;i>=0;i--)
{
    list[i]=binary%2;
    binary/=2;
}
```

This will be correct

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

```
#include <bitset>
int main() {
    std::bitset<32> bits("01000100011100111111000000000000");
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, would you mind explaining to me how to use std::bitset to read something like that using std::cin?

Comment: It has the usual [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2)

Comment: I Googled it, didn't quite meet the criteria for the assignment of not using classes, but gave me an idea for organizing the set of numbers. Thanks a lot, man, appreciate it.